# Regenerate table on checkbox checked with another sql query in the Flask backend

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, datatables

I have a problem finding the right solution for my web interface: 
I have a table created with Datatables framework. On backend Flask

By default table is populated from Mysql DB with query `SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE status != 'OK'`

But I want to add a checkbox with the name `Show all records`.
By checking this checkbox backend should use another query to populate `SELECT * FROM test_table`
Basically, select everything.

Javascript code:

```
$('#main_table').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/index_get_data",
        "dataType": "json",
        "dataSrc": "data",
        "contentType": "application/json"
    },
    "columns": [{
            "data": "id"
        }, {
            "data": "version"
        }
    ]
});
```

Python in Flask

```
@app.route('/index')
@app.route('/')
def index():
   return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/index_get_data')
def main_info():
    if query_all is not None:
        sql_query = "SELECT * FROM test_table "
    else:
        sql_query = "SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE status != 'OK'"
    conn = mysql.connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_query)
    conn.close()
    row_headers = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]
    rv = cursor.fetchall()
    json_data = []
    for result in rv:
        json_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers, result)))
    return_data = {'data': json_data}
    return json.dumps(return_data, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
```

Javascript function that catches checkbox checking event

```
const checkbox = document.getElementById('chkBox')
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        if (event.target.checked) {
            $.post("/select_all", {
                select_all: "True"
            });
        }
    })
```

And here, unfortunately, I stuck. I can't find correct way to reload page with non default query.
...

Comment: can you break down what your stuck on? I figure there's 2 possible sticking points: 1. ensuring api call has a flag saying which query to do 2. the actual reloading such as the [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, you could have achieved that feature entirely client-side, by loading your full data set upon table initialization, having hidden column 'status' and doing `search('OK')`/`search('')` against that column upon `Show all records` unchecked/checked.

However, if `status = 'OK'` records stand the least part of your dataset and entire list of records is required not that often, it would be faster to do that server-side, indeed.

For that, you simply need to trigger [`ajax.reload()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) against your table from within POST success callback:

```
const checkbox = document.getElementById('chkBox')
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        if (event.target.checked) {
            $.post("/select_all", {
                select_all: "True",
                success: () => $('#main_table').DataTable().ajax.reload()
            });
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks ! You answer was very helpful to find correct code!